# Proving Something is a vector space?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

If I am given a DE such as y''+2y'+y=0 , and am asked if it is a vector space, can I show that IS is indeed a vector space because the solution can be written as y=cv+du, where v=e^-t and u=te^-t ? And say it is a linear combination span{v,u}?

Can you give some examples of DE that are NOT vector spaces so I can get a better understanding..

Comment: I suppose you mean that the *solutions* form a vector space; not that the DE itself *is* a vector space...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation in your question is an example of a *homogeneous linear differential equation*. The **solutions** to differential equations of this kind, indeed form a vector space (not the differential equation itself!). You can verify that:

- the zero function satisfies the equation;
- if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions, then so is the sum $y_1+y_2$ (due to linearity);
- if $y$ is a solution and $c$ a scalar, then $cy$ is also a solution (linearity again).

Solutions to other kinds of differential equations, e.g. nonlinear differential equations, in general do not form a vector space.

If you want an easy example: simply change your differential equation to a non-homogeneous one.

Comment: do all non homogeneous work? like what if it equals cosine? does it still not work even? Non homogeous but it has the zero vector, no?

Comment: It's not just about being *homogeneous* (or not). You can have a non-linear differential equation with the zero function as one of the solutions, but that doesn't mean the solutions form a vector space (there are more conditions for that!). But a(ny) differential equation that is not satisfied by the zero function is an easy example of a differential equation where the solutions *do not* form a vector space.

Comment: if a DE equals a trig function, is the zero function satisfied then?

Comment: No, if I guess what you mean correctly. Perhaps you should give an example of a DE you have in mind, but you can plug in $y=0$ and check...